# Exception when using a @ResultSetMapping on a native SQL query with a Spring Data JPA Repository?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, nativequery

I'm currently building a native SQL query with Spring Data JPA that uses a `@SqlResultSetMapping`. The query looks filters the rows based on certain parameters and then returns all of the columns of an entity table plus additionally it calculates another column on the fly. Something like this:

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "Entity.searchBySearchParams",
        resultSetMapping = "SearchResultMapping",
        query = "select entity.*, (*calculation*) as anotherField from ..."
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "SearchResultMapping",
        entities = @EntityResult(entityClass = Entity.class),
        columns = @ColumnResult(name = "anotherField", type = double.class)
)
public class Entity { ... }
```

And then I'm trying to call this native, named query from my repository (which extends `JpaRepository<T, Long>`) like that:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, name = "Entity.searchBySearchParams")
List<Object[]> searchBySearchParams( ... lots of params ... );
```

Where I'm expecting `searchBySearchParams(...)[0]` to be of type `Entity` and `searchBySearchParams(...)[1]` of type `Double`.

Unfortunately I'm getting this exception when trying to call the above repository method:

```
    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return
    
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
....
```

Which is weird since calling the query and applying my result set mapping directly by invoking the `EntityManage#createNamedQuery` method worked perfectly fine.

Am I missing something or should I post this to the Spring Data Jira? Neither JPA's nor Spring's documentation provided information for my case ...

**More Background Info:**

Actually the additional column anotherField is a transitive property on my Entity. I haven't found a way of mapping that column to the transitive property, which is why my repository method currently returns Object[].

Comment: Use alias for `entity` and `entity.*` -> `entity`

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean create a wrapper object that contains both the entity columns and `anotherField` ?